# Issue with openssl-1.1.0f while compiling app

Tags: android-ndk, openssl

I am getting an error in openssl while compiling app with openssl-1.1.0f using android-ndk-r8e.
Please help me, I am not able to figure out this.

Below are the errors getting in openssl.

```
1) libcrypto.a(init.o):init.c:function ossl_init_base_ossl_: error: undefined reference to 'atexit'
2) error: invalid use of incomplete type 'SSL_CTX {aka struct ssl_ctx_st}'
/ossl_typ.h:145:16: error: forward declaration of 'SSL_CTX {aka struct ssl_ctx_st}'

3) error: invalid use of incomplete type 'SSL {aka struct ssl_st}'
ossl_typ.h:144:16: error: forward declaration of 'SSL {aka struct ssl_st}'
```

Comment: For (1) you seems to be missing a library during link (Standard C Library?). For (2) and (3), your code is calling functions or reaching into data structures that are private in OpenSSL 1.1.0 (but were public in 1.0.2 and below). Also see [OpenSSL 1.1.0 Changes | Compatibility Layer](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_1.1.0_Changes#Compatibility_Layer) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: thanks for the reply, for (1) I am not able to figure out how to link standard C library because the error is coming when compiling the app for android. For other (2) and (3) I am getting error in "pSslCtx->app_verify_arg = ctxdata", now how I can access these property, please help me.